# Mac 10.9 Accessibility

Tags: macos, security, system-preferences

The Mac OS X 10.9 has Accessibility settings moved to different pane, now its been moved into security and privacy and it is per app based kindly look at the following screenshot ,[image]

If we want our app to have enabled Accessibility feature then we can drag and drop it , but however being developer how to add our application to this list?? any one faced similar problem can help .

Comment: The entire point of this security setting is that you, as a developer, *cannot* grant your app rights to control the UI; it requires user approval.

Comment: But as developer we should be able to enable for our own applications, since apple has now made accessibility based on per applciations it makes sense that as developer i should be able to enable the this for my own applications, but as of now only way through is using AXProcessTrusted but the API requires that the very first time our app get launched it required to be restarted and this results in bad user expirenece

Answer (score 6):

In OS X 10.9 Mavericks, `AXAPIEnabled()` [has been deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ApplicationServices/Reference/AXUIElement_header_reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AXAPIEnabled).

`AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions` can be used instead:

```
NSDictionary *options = @{(id)kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt : @YES};
BOOL accessibilityEnabled = AXIsProcessTrustedWithOptions((CFDictionaryRef)options);
```

If you pass in `YES` for `kAXTrustedCheckOptionPrompt`, the system will show the user a helpful dialog with a link to the correct Security & Privacy pane in System Preferences:

> "YourApp.app would like to control this computer using accessibility features."

[image]